# Azure AD app: Grant permissions to a separate site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, azureadapps

Does anyone know if it's possible to grant permissions to an Azure App to a separate site collection?

And if it's possible, can we also grant permissions to a separate subsite and a list/library?

I will be very grateful for any comments!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SharePoint Graph APIs in Azure do not support resource-specific consent. If you need that functionality, you would need to change to using the traditional SharePoint Add-in permission model.

Comment: Those are SharePoint Graph APIs (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/site?view=graph-rest-1.0) you're working with. As for which is appropriate, delegated vs application, depends on what you need to do. You can update your question with the specifics if you wish.

Comment: I don't think it's graph API. It even shows a message at the top of the screenshot advising me to use Graph API instead of this endpoiny.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/sharepoint-rest-graph :-)

Comment: Trevor, I have created a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109410/azure-app-registration-classic-rest-api-vs-graph-api)

Comment: I am accepting the asnwer, but I am still confused about the "Graph API" part.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Graph API now supports permissions for specific site collections - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/blogs/controlling-app-access-on-specific-sharepoint-site-collections/

[image]